# Count Number of Digits in an array (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

let's say I have an array
arr[5]={5,2,3,2,5} and i wrote following program for it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n;
  cout<<"Enter Length of Elements= ";
  cin>>n;
  int arr[50];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      cout<<"Enter Number=";
      cin>>arr[i];
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      int countNum=1;


      for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
      {
          if(arr[i]==arr[j])
          {
              if(i>0)
              {
                  int countNum2=0;


                  for(int k=0;k>i;k++)
                  {
                      //bool repeat=false;

                      if(arr[i]==arr[k])
                      {
                        //repeat=false;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          countNum2++;
                      }
                  }
                  if(countNum2==i)
                  {
                     countNum++;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                countNum++;
              }
          }
          else
          {
              for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
              {
                  if(arr[k]==arr[i])
                  {

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      countNum=1;
                  }

              }
          }

      }
      cout<<arr[i]<<" has appeared "<<countNum<< "Times"<<endl;

  }

    return 0;
}
```

but why I am getting
5 has appeared 2 Times

2 has appeared 1 Time

3 has appeared 1 Time

2 has appeared 1 Time

5 has appeared 1 Time

instead of

5 has appeared 2 Times

2 has appeared 2 Times

3 has appeared 1 Times

so how to fix my program 
help!

Comment: number of digits or just the count of a number?

Comment: "why I am getting 5 has appeared two times" - what do you mean? Isn't that the expected output or you meant 2? Also the use of so many loops is completely unecessary.

Comment: Do you want the count of each unique digit in an array?

Comment: i don't want to print those numbers again and again who have been printed

Comment: Thats is exactly whats meant by "unique".

Comment: Since you're scanning the array element by element, and looking at what's left in the rest of the array, you never remove numbers which are potentially duplicated. You're bound to print the same number more than once if it appears again later.

Comment: This problem is known as histogram. Even if you find the solution for the particular problem you struggle with, I suggest to look into known algorithms that solve histograms efficiently.

Comment: This problem is an ideal candidate for using the debugger. I strongly recommend you learn how to use it. It allows you to step over execution of your code line by line and inspect the variables at each step to see what has happened.

Comment: @ProBoy Consider accepting an answer which helps/provided the solution! Also if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

That's what you exactly need (amount of each number in array):

```cpp
// we'll store amounts of numbers like key-value pairs.
// std::map does exactly what we need. As a key we will
// store a number and as a key - corresponding counter
std::map<int, size_t> digit_count;

// it is simpler for explanation to have our
// array on stack, because it helps us not to
// think about some language-specific things
// like memory management and focus on the algorithm
const int arr[] = { 5, 2, 3, 2, 5 };

// iterate over each element in array
for(const auto elem : arr) 
{
    // operator[] of std::map creates default-initialized
    // element at the first access. For size_t it is 0.
    // So we can just add 1 at each appearance of the number 
    // in array to its counter.
    digit_count[elem] += 1;
}

// Now just iterate over all elements in our container and
// print result. std::map's iterator is a pair, which first element
// is a key (our number in array) and second element is a value
// (corresponding counter)
for(const auto& elem : digit_count) {
    std::cout << elem.first << " appeared " << elem.second << " times\n";
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/_WTvAm

Well, let's write some basic code, but firstly let's consider an algorithm (it is not the most efficient one, but more understandable):

The most understandable way is to iterate over each number in array and increment some corresponding counter by one. Let it be a pair with the first element to be our number and the second to be a counter:

```cpp
struct pair {
    int number;
    int counter;
};
```

Other part of algorithm will be explained in code below

```cpp
// Say that we know an array length and its elements
size_t length = // user-defined, typed by user, etc.
int* arr = new int[length];
// input elements

// There will be no more, than length different numbers
pair* counts = new pair[length];

// Initialize counters
// Each counte will be initialized to zero explicitly (but it is not obligatory,
// because in struct each field is initialized by it's default
// value implicitly)
for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    counts[i].counter = 0;
}

// Iterate over each element in array: arr[i]
for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // Now we need to find corresponding counter in our counters.
    size_t index_of_counter = 0;

    // Corresponding counter is the first counter with 0 value (in case when
    // we meet current number for the first time) or the counter that have
    // the corresponding value equal to arr[i]
    for(; counts[index_of_counter].counter != 0 && counts[index_of_counter].number != arr[i]; index_of_counter++)
        ; // Do nothing here - index_of_counter is incrementing in loop-statement

    // We found an index of our counter
    // Let's assign the value (it will assign a value
    // to newly initialized pair and won't change anything
    // in case of already existing value).
    counts[index_of_counter].number = arr[i];

    // Increment our counter. It'll became 1 in case of new
    // counter, because of zero assigned to it a bit above.
    counts[index_of_counter].counter += 1;
}

// Now let's iterate over all counters until we reach the first
// containing zero (it means that this counter and all after it are not used)
for(size_t i = 0; i < length && counts[i].counter > 0; i++) {
    std::cout << counts[i].number << " appeared " << counts[i].counter << " times\n";
}

// correctly delete dynamically allocated memory
delete[] counts;
delete[] arr;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hN33Pn

Moreover it is exactly the same solution like with `std::map` (the same idea), so I hope it can help you to understand, how the first solution works inside

Comment: I am not advanced in c++ 
i am on basics

Comment: i don't know about maps

Comment: @ProBoy, I'm writing a basic solution now, it'll appear in my answer soon :)

Comment: *I am not advanced in c++ i am on basics* -- It is subjective as to what are "basics" of C++.  A `map` is basic, and learning what they are and how to use them are "basics".  If you want a comparison with another language Python, the "map" in Python is learned almost in the first week of learning the language.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, but in python `map` is completely different thing: it is a function, that applies a function to each element of collection. In C++ it is a container!

Comment: You mistook what I stated, and why I put the word "map" in quotes.  In Python, you have a dictionary,  when do they start teaching dictionaries in Python?  Also, your updated code introduces `new []` and `delete []`.  Are they "basic" C++ or is it advanced?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, sorry for my misunderstanding :) You're right. But actually `std::map` is a bit more complicted to understand for beginners in comparison to Python's `dict`, because of templates... And one more thing - `std::map` is not a part of C++ language (`dict` is native Python's type) - it is a part of STL library. STL is explained a bit later (probably after classes and introduction into templates).

Comment: `new[]` and `delete[]` both correspond to dynamic memory allocation. I think that question's author is familiar with this technique

Comment: TBH, the first example is more understandable to a novice programmer than the second.  A beginner will look at the first example, and just ask what is map and why the small amount of code works.  Once they understand what a map is, they will easily see how the first example works.  With the second example, the beginner has to know what `struct` is, what `new` and `delete` are, etc.  Too much to grasp, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don't remove the duplicates or assign an array which effectively stores the count of each unique element in your array.

Also the use of so many loops is completely unnecessary.

You just need to implement two loops, outer one going through all the elements and the inner one checking for dupes first (using an array to check frequency/occurence status) and counting appearance of each element seperately with a variable used as a counter.

Set a counter array (with the corresponding size of your taken array) with a specific value (say zero) and change that value when same element occurs while traversing the array, to trigger not to count for that value again.

Then transfer the count value from the counter variable to the counter array (the one which we set and which distinguishes between duplicates) each time the inner loop finishes iterating over the whole array. (i.e. place it after the values are counted)

With a little bit of modification, your code will work as you would want it to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n;
  cout<<"Enter Length of Elements = ";
  cin>>n;
  int arr[50];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      cout<<"Enter Number = ";
      cin>>arr[i];
  }

  int counter[50];
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    counter[i]=0;

    // Our counter variable, but counts will be transferred to count[] later on:
    int tempcount;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   // Each distinct element occurs once atleast so initialize to one:
        tempcount = 1;
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            // If dupe is found: 
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                tempcount++;

                // Ensuring not to count frequency of same element again:
                counter[j] = 1;
            }
        }

        // If occurence of current element is not counted before:
        if(counter[i] != 1)
            counter[i] = tempcount;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(counter[i] != 0)
            printf("%d has appeared %d times.\n", arr[i], counter[i]);
    }
 return 0;
}
```

I used a variable `tempcount` to count occurence of each element and a zero-initialized array `count` to get the dupes checked (by setting it to 1 for a duplicate entry, and not counting it if it qualifies as 1) first. Then I transferred the counted occurence values to `counter[]` from `tempcount` at each outer loop iteration. (for all the unique elements)

Comment: You must dynamically allocate memory here `int count[n]={0};`, because `n` is not compile-time constant